# UIView animateWithDuration works every other time with .alpha parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to animate `.alpha` parameter for one of my views. Below is a block of code:

```
- (IBAction)closeImg:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^ {

          imgViewList.alpha = 0.0;  

          [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];

          self.navigationController.toolbar.barTintColor = nil;
          self.navigationController.toolbar.clipsToBounds = NO;

          NSMutableArray *toolbarButtons = [self.toolbarItems mutableCopy];

          [toolbarButtons removeObject:self.editButton];
          [toolbarButtons removeObject:self.spaceBar];
          [toolbarButtons removeObject:self.deleteImgButton];
          [toolbarButtons removeObject:self.closeButton];
          [toolbarButtons removeObject:self.shareBtn];
          [toolbarButtons removeObject:self.dismiss2];
          [toolbarButtons removeObject:self.upload2];

          [toolbarButtons addObject:self.backBtn];
          if (![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"imageToDisplay"] isEqualToString:@"newsImg"]) {
              [toolbarButtons addObject:self.spaceBar];
              [toolbarButtons addObject:self.menuBtn];
          }

          [self setToolbarItems:toolbarButtons animated:YES];
          self.view.window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelNormal;

          [imgUpload removeAllObjects];


          pgScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pgScroll.frame.size.width, imgList.frame.origin.y+imgList.frame.size.height+20);
          pgScroll.contentInset = contentInsets;
          pgScroll.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
    }
}
```

It works BUT every once in a while (every 4th or 5th time) it doesn't. The `imgViewList` doesn't fade away. **What can possibly happen once in a while???** cuz usually it either works all the time or it doesn't. Or maybe some other part of that code makes negative effect?

Comment: So you are animating the alpha to 0 when you press close button.. Where are you actually setting the alpha to 1??? The bug is not in the above snippet.. it is somewhere else in your code..

Comment: I'm setting it before... to show image gallery: `imgViewList.alpha = 1.0` after clicking on image thumb. This part works with no problem ever. By the way it's done with the same type of animation in 0.15.

Comment: Well without further information and/or more code, it is impossible to answer your question. All you have is a simple UIView animateWithDuration that sets the alpha of an imageView to 0. There is not a single thing wrong in the current snippet in your post so you won't be able to get any answers anytime soon unless more info is provided.. Something else is going on elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I'll update my code with its full version is a second

Comment: Except that a lot of that work your doing in the animation block is not animatable. (Adding and removing views and toolbar buttons, manipulating scrollviews, etc.)